# Change the value of MaxRequestLen via .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, apache-2.4

Is it possible to change the value of `MaxRequestLen` without root access to my Apache 1and1.co.uk dedicated server (managed version)? I was hoping to be able to change the value via .htaccess? Does anyone know if this is possible?

I investigated if the value could be changed via a php.ini file but `MaxRequestLen` is server configuration rather than a PHP variable.

Please note plain CGI is enabled on the server (the server has no Fast CGI).

**Update:**

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
MaxRequestLen 31457280
</IfModule>
```

Would something like this work in .htaccess?

Comment: What is it now? What do you think it should be?

Comment: I've actually asked 1and1 for the value they're using 2 times now and both times support haven't answered the question. I believe it's now 131072 bytes because that is the default since Apache 2.3.6. The default used to be 1GB!

Comment: So isn't this an issue that has to be directed to those at 1and1?

Comment: I wished 1and1 would help. They've refused to increase the value. That's why I'm hoping I can do it myself via .htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upgrade from apache 2.2 to apache 2.4 changed the directive from MaxRequestLen to    [FcgidMaxRequestLen](http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html#fcgidmaxrequestlen). As you can see from the linked documentation, the FcgidMaxRequestLen directive is only usable [in the Server Config and Virtual Host contexts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/directive-dict.html#Context).

So to answer your question, No you can't make this change in the .htaccess.